# SAS Problem: Data infile leads to 0 observations

Tags: sas

I'm having an issue with SAS 9.4. See code below;

```
data myData;
infile 'D:\folder1\folder2\myData.xlsx';
input var1 var2 var3;
```

This results in SAS executing this successfully, recognizing the 3 variables but containing 0 observations. Is there something wrong with how the code is written? Has anyone encountered this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually you would use PROC IMPORT or the XLSX LIBNAME engine to read data from an XLSX workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an XLSX file is binary (in particular it is just a ZIP file) your data step is not finding any lines of text to read.  Most likely the reason you got 0 observations is that when searching for the second or third space delimited word to read it went past the end of the file.  So the data step stopped at the INPUT statement and never reached the end of the first iteration to write an observation.

You will need to either use PROC IMPORT or a LIBNAME statement using the XLSX engine to read an XLSX file.  Or use Excel to save the file as a delimited text file, then you could read using a simple data step.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in an Excel format, you should be able to do PROC IMPORT to read it in.

```
PROC IMPORT DATAFILE="D:\folder1\folder2\myData.xlsx" DBMS=XLSX OUT=myData;
RUN;
```

Comment: I would assume that a file with an extension of `xlsx` should be read using the `xlsx` engine and not the `xls` engine.  Unless the creator of the file used the wrong extension when making the file.